# Como exportar classes, métodos ou constantes em um módulo do Python

Tags: python, typescript, módulo-python

Olá, estou começando a trabalhar com Python e tenho uma boa experiência com Typescript. No Typescript, eu tenho costume de criar módulos quando preciso organizar meu código, assim:

```
<rootDir>
    domain
        index.ts
        person.ts
    models
        index.ts
        person.model.ts
```

Onde nos arquivos `index.ts` eu faço a exportação do conteúdo do arquivo quando necessário, assim como no próprio arquivo, assim:

**/domain/person.ts**

```
export class Person { ... }
```

**/domain/index.ts**

```js
export * from './person'
```

Se eu tentar acessar esses elementos dentro do modulo `models`, eu só teria que fazer isso:

**/models/person.model.ts**

```js
import { Person } from '../domain'
export class PersonModel extends Person { ... }
```

No Python, estou criando a seguinte estrutura:

```
<rootDir>
    domain
        __init_.py
        person.py
    models
        __init.py
        person_model.py
```

Onde eu tenho as classes

**/domain/person.py**

```py
class Person():
    ...
```

E tento puxar a classe `Person` dentro do arquivo do módulo de model para que eu possa definí-la na criação da classe `PersonModel` assim:

**/models/person_model.py**

```py
from domain import product

class ProductModel(product.Product):
    ...
```

Minha dúvida é o seguinte:

- Se eu estou usando módulos em Python, porque que não consigo importar diretamente  a classe `Product` como faço no Typescript?
- Existe alguma configuração necessária para poder usar isso dessa forma?

> **NOTA:** a intenção dessa questão é para abrir meus conhecimentos e conseguir assimilar Python de uma forma mais simples baseando no que eu tenho de Typescript e assim aprender mais rapido...

Comment: Não seria `from domain.product import Product` o que você quer?

Comment: A intenção é exatamente não precisar acessar o `domain.product` para que eu possa chegar até essa classe. Em Typescript isso é chamado de "barrel", estou vendo como poderia usar esse recurso em Python pra ficar mais claro a lógica das soluções

Comment: Mas em TS você não fez `import { Person } from '../domain'`? Acessa o "domain" igual, não?

Comment: Pra você acessar a `Person`, que está dentro de `domain`, ela tem que estar declarada como exportada dentro do arquivo index, caso contrário vc tem que acessar o arquivo dela diretamente usando `domain/person`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dentro da pasta "models" seus módulos de Python vão enxergar só os arquivos e pastas que estão ali dentro, *e* o que estiver no PYTHONPATH.

Então, você usa ou o nome completo da pasta "domain", incluindo o nome do projeto:

```
from meuprojeto.domain.person import Person
```

Ou usa importação relativa, adicionando um "." além do primeiro no prefixo
do módulo, pra cada pasta que quiser "subir":

```
from ..domain.person import Person
```

(Só funciona se esse arquivo.py em particular for importado como parte do projeto  todo também, isso é, o caminho dele vai ser `meuprojeto.models.person_model` )

Em ambos os casos, é necessário que o Python esteja enxergando sua hierarquia de módulos como um pacote - isso é, é necessário que o "meuprojeto", acima das pastas "domain" e "models" esteja no Pythonpath. Em geral, quando criamos um projeto em Python, essa pasta mais externa vai ter um arquvo "setup.py" com as informações de instalação - se você tiver o setup.py, execute o comando "pip install -e ." nessa pasta (acima do "meuprojeto") - isso vai considerar que o projeto que você está editando e criando é parte do ambiente de Python que você está usando. Então, estando em qualquer pasta no seu computador, você poderá chamar só o arquivo específico com uma linha como `python3 -m meuprojeto.models.person_model`. Se não tiver o setup.py, é só chamar o interpretador a partir dessa pasta, acima do "meuprojeto", ou inclui-la na variável de ambiente "PYTHONPATH".

## "exportando"

Em Python, todos os objetos de todos os módulos são visíveis para qualquer código - o que define se são públicos ou não é a convenção: se o nome do arquivo, variável ou objeto começar com "_", usários desse projeto/módulo não devem mexer diretamente com o mesmo.  Então não há necessidade de exportação -

Agora na prática, é comum termos coisas "mais públicas" do que outras - vamos supor que dentro do seu arquivo "domain/person.py" há várias helper-functions que fazem sentido para os métodos da classe Person, mas que não tem por que alguém "de fora" usar. Colcoar todas essas functions como "privadas" com nomes começando com "_" só vai atrapalhar sua legibilidade. 
O que se costuma fazer é expor a classe de mais alto nível - os nomes  que o usuário do seu projeto vão de fato usar - no arquivo `__init__.py` de cada pasta.

Assim, você poderia por dentro do `domain.__init__.py` um `from .person import Person`. Aí, outros pacotes que forem usar esse model vão fazer:
`from meuprojeto.domain import Person` (em vez de `from meuprojeto.domain.person import Person`).

Em projetos grandes, pode ser desejável não ter que ficar editando o `__init__` para incluir todas as classes de todos os arquivos naquela pasta, então pode ser ok, ter algum código usando `for` e introspecção do sistema de arquivos mesmo para fazer as importações automaticamente - mas esse tipo de código em geral fica no framework, não no projeto.

E, para fins de deixar a resposta completa, o Python também faz uso da variável de módulo `__all__` para indicar quais nomes vão ser importados com "*" naquele módulo.

Então, voltando ao caso de que o "persons.py" tenha algumas classes que você quer deixar como "mais públicas", e várias helper-functions e variáveis de módulo - você pode no final do arquivo `persons.py` colocar:

```
__all__ = ["Person", "OtherPerson", "VIPerson"]  # (as classes públicas)
```

e no `__init__.py` correspondente usar `from .person import *`, para trazer só os objetos que tem os nomes em `__all__`

Comment: realmente eu percebi que eu consigo fazer algo muito semelhante ao que eu faço no Typescript (`export * from './persons'`) ao declarar `from .persons import *`